# Different result when doing casting

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm running the following script and get different result when casting to int and float!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
feat1 = cv2.imread('0002.png')
feat2 = cv2.imread('0001.png')

dist1 = np.sum(np.power((feat1 - feat2), 2), axis = 2)
dist2 = np.sum(np.power((feat1 - feat2).astype(int), 2), axis = 2)
dist3 = np.sum(np.power((feat1 - feat2).astype(float), 2), axis = 2)

print dist1
print dist2
print dist3
```

Result:

```
[[308 387 389 ..., 176 305 344]
 [566 587 424 ..., 152 474 309]
 [409 293 377 ..., 381 209 161]
 ..., 
 [373  80 499 ..., 366 185 354]
 [ 89 627 526 ..., 211 245 305]
 [233 361 491 ..., 120 414 269]]

[[  6452   8835   1925 ..., 121776 126257 140120]
 [  5942  10059   1960 ..., 110744 123354 123701]
 [  6041   3365    377 ..., 103549 119761 113569]
 ..., 
 [  2933   3408   4595 ...,  96622  98489  93794]
 [  4697   4211   6158 ..., 101331  97013  94769]
 [   233   1897   4075 ..., 106104 104606  95501]]

[[   6452.    8835.    1925. ...,  121776.  126257.  140120.]
 [   5942.   10059.    1960. ...,  110744.  123354.  123701.]
 [   6041.    3365.     377. ...,  103549.  119761.  113569.]
 ..., 
 [   2933.    3408.    4595. ...,   96622.   98489.   93794.]
 [   4697.    4211.    6158. ...,  101331.   97013.   94769.]
 [    233.    1897.    4075. ...,  106104.  104606.   95501.]]
```

How should one understand this?

Link to the images: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k11s5gek47hxd4v/AAB9M31xpiCUUr1N1RXbOJnWa?dl=0

Result of feat1 - feat1.astype(int)

```
[[308 387 389 ..., 176 305 344]
 [566 587 424 ..., 152 474 309]
 [409 293 377 ..., 381 209 161]
 ..., 
 [373  80 499 ..., 366 185 354]
 [ 89 627 526 ..., 211 245 305]
 [233 361 491 ..., 120 414 269]]
[[  6452   8835   1925 ..., 121776 126257 140120]
 [  5942  10059   1960 ..., 110744 123354 123701]
 [  6041   3365    377 ..., 103549 119761 113569]
 ..., 
 [  2933   3408   4595 ...,  96622  98489  93794]
 [  4697   4211   6158 ..., 101331  97013  94769]
 [   233   1897   4075 ..., 106104 104606  95501]]
[[   6452.    8835.    1925. ...,  121776.  126257.  140120.]
 [   5942.   10059.    1960. ...,  110744.  123354.  123701.]
 [   6041.    3365.     377. ...,  103549.  119761.  113569.]
 ..., 
 [   2933.    3408.    4595. ...,   96622.   98489.   93794.]
 [   4697.    4211.    6158. ...,  101331.   97013.   94769.]
 [    233.    1897.    4075. ...,  106104.  104606.   95501.]]
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 ..., 
 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

Comment: Try using 2 really small images (3x3 pixels). Post their matrices together with the results. Otherwise your data is not really reproducible and I find it hard to believe that your results are possible.

Comment: can you try `feat1.astype(int)-feat2.astype(int)` and see if that makes a difference
?

Comment: Link to the images https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k11s5gek47hxd4v/AAB9M31xpiCUUr1N1RXbOJnWa?dl=0

Comment: `feat1` and `feat2` seem to be `np.uint8` arrays, i.e. unsigned 8-bit integers. Wherever `feat2 > feat1` your subtraction will therefore return an incorrect result unless you cast to a signed dtype first, as in @RNar's comment.